# OS process management

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling

Assume a process execution interrupted at the middle and CPU started executing a different process.How does the OS handle this situation?

Comment: This is described in many operating system textbooks.  There would be little point in us repeating information that's already available in standard resources.  We expect you to do a significant amount of study/research before asking here.  Have you already done that?  Can you edit your question to tell us what you've been reading, what you already understand, and what specifically you are unsure about?

Comment: Just to underline D.W.'s point, one quite good textbook that is available for free: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/

Answer (score 0):

The way you worded the question, it sounds like the CPU starts executing a different process, and the operating system must react to this. But this is not how it works.

There are two ways to switch between processes. Both involve the operating system. One way is if the process [calls the operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). The other way is if an [interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) happens; in this case the CPU invokes an [interrupt handler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler) which is part of the operating system. In both cases, the operating system may take the decision to either return to the previous process, or to switch to a different process.